# problem with the ocean modifier, black reflection

Tags: ocean-simulation

[image]I try to integrate  a terrain with an heightmap in a middle of the ocean. aside the  scale of the waves, I would like to fix this dark reflection, I don't know what it possibly could be,  again  follow a tutorial and it's not something I understand, that 's a  bit complex for me  with the nodes.  someone have an advice ? thanks

---

it seems to be better, start to see reflexion instead of black  [image] increasing  the min light bounce

Comment: it is probably the light bounces... unfortunately this means you will trade more render time for increased accuracy

Comment: thank you that solved the problem